# Kubernetes volume hostpath with symlink not created

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I've got a service defined with a volume where the parent directory is a symlink to another device. The volume definition in the yaml is like the below:

```
  volumes:
  -name: service-logs
   hostPath:
     path: /tmp/logs/service-logs
     type: DirectoryOrCreate
```

and /tmp/logs is a symlink to /data/logs. When I try to start the pod, it fails to create /tmp/logs/service-logs.

Is there a way to get this working? Or does kubernetes not resolve the symlink?

Answer (score 0):

I recreated your issue with Kubernetes 1.14.
I used following yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: test-pd
spec:
  containers:
  - image: busybox
    name: test-container
    command: ["sleep"]
    args: ["3600"]
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /test-pd
      name: test-volume
  volumes:
  - name: test-volume
    hostPath:
      path: /data/folder
      type: DirectoryOrCreate
  nodeSelector:
    kubernetes.io/hostname: cluster-1
```

On node `cluster-1` I created directory and symlink to it:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root        root           5 Mar 28 16:56 data -> data2
d--------- 3 testuser testuser       4096 Mar 28 17:04 data2
```

Even with no permissions to write in `data2` directory `folder` was created. Processes inside of the pod were able to write to it. This is due to the fact that kubelet process, responsible for mounting volumes to a container, is run by root.

Comment: Please post output of `kubectl describe pod FAILED_POD` to troubleshoot your case.